# Django How to setup an email

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a password-reset function in Django. I want to choose a custom email (in HTML). I can't find any docs and I think my files are completely wrong but I really don't know how Django's email service work. I guessed by other peoples questions on stackoverflow.

Here are my files:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('reset', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='authenticate/reset.html'), {
            'template_name': 'email/test.html',
            'html_email_template_name': 'email/test.html',
            'email_template_name': 'email/test.txt',
            'subject_template_name': 'email/test.txt',
        }, name='password_reset'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='authenticate/reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

]
```

test.html:

```
    <html style="font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>E-Mail</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header style="background-color:#fff;">
            <div class="navbar-container">
                <div class="navbar-branding" style="margin:0;">
                    <p style="margin:0;">Logo</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div style="background-color:#f0f0f0;padding-left:10vw;padding-right:10vw;padding-top:200px;min-height:50vh;">
            <div style="background-color:#fff;color:#aaa;">
                <table style="margin:auto;color:#aaa;padding: 20px;">
                    <th>
                        <h1>{% block subject %}{% endblock %}</h1>
                        <p>{% block body %}{% endblock %}</p>
                    </th>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% include 'template/footer.html' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

test.txt:

```
{% block subject %}
    Password reset
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    Reset your password <a href="{{ site_name }}">here</a>.
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: so basically you want to know how to setup emailing for django?

Comment: What does "choose a custom email in HTML" mean?

Comment: @Tsuna yes. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/ for your backend when receiving post requests, as for the html part pass the values to the api you created